# Change the permissions of files and directories excluding one directory

Tags: chmod, find

I'm trying to change the permissions of files and directories, excluding one directory though. What I've got is:

```
find ! -name test -exec chmod -R 700 {} \;
```

test being the directory that I need excluded, while the other files and directories need to be 700 permissions access.

Comment: Presumably you mean `find . ! -name ...`? Also, do consider different permissions for files and folders (you don't want +x on all files). Also, from `man find`: `To ignore a directory and the files under it, use -prune;`

Answer (score 2):

To ignore a directory, you should use `-prune`. Consider something like this:

```
find . -name test -prune -o -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \; -o -type f -execdir chmod 600 {} +
```

Explanation:

1. `-name test -prune`: `-prune`, if the tests before it are true, and the current file is a directory, skip it, else return false.
2. `-o -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;`: if `-prune` returns false, then these options are applied (as `-o` is OR), and this applies `chmod 700` if the file is a directory.
3. `-o -type f -execdir chmod 600 {} +`: if both the above tests return false, then apply `chmod 600` as it's not a directory. `execdir` is "a much more secure method for invoking commands", according to the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/find.1.html), which also gives the reasons.

Comment: For some reason, this still doesn't change the permissions of a file after I've done it

Comment: Well actually...
`find . -name test -prune -o -type d -exec chmod -R 700 {} \;`
this works to change all the permissions but it doesn't exclude the test directory + the files in that test directory

Comment: @user3434743 what is your directory tree?

Comment: cs211/test is the directory I am working in.

Comment: I meant my directory is cs211/a1 and a1 has 4 directories including the test directory.

Comment: @user3434743 I used this test command to build this command: `find . -name test -prune -o -type d -exec basename {} \; -o -type f -ls`. If you do recursive chmod/chown, then the moment you hit a parent folder of test, test is affected too.